# Storing variable, then put into array, verse putting directly into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing an api call, and when I get the response, I am doing this.

```
      request.get('https://example.com', function(error, response, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        name = body.name
        image = body.picture.data.url
        userList[i].name = name;
        userList[i].image = image;
        console.log(userList[i])
      }
```

That seems to work, I can see the variables in the array. But if I do this

```
      request.get('https://example.com', function(error, response, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        userList[i].name = body.name;
        userList[i].image = body.picture.data.url;
        console.log(userList[i])
      }
```

Then print the userList array, it shows nothing in the name or image property.

What is making it not store correctly in the array?

Comment: please add the rest of the code, including the part where you log the array

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working with and without variables, it won't matter. See example

```js
var body = {name:'Name', picture : {data: {url:'stackoverflow.com'}}}
var i = 0;
var userList = [];
userList[i] = {};
userList[i].name = body.name;
userList[i].image = body.picture.data.url;
console.log(userList);
console.log(userList[i]);
```

Comment: It will not work with the second example I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to push object in array

```
request.get('https://example.com', function(error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    var data = {};
    var userList = [];
    data.name = body.name;
    data.image = body.picture.data.url;
    userList.push(data);
    console.log(userList[userList.length - 1]);
  }
```

Comment: userList[i] already is an associative array, so push wouldn't be helpful here.